# Converting String from E notation to "million, billion, trillion, etc)

Tags: c#

In my program it says the float value for how much currency the person has. Currently if its a huge number say 200,000,000, it displays it as "2E+08" When I would rather it display "200 Million" Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried anything? Did you get any error?

Comment: If you are dealing with actual money, never use a floating point type.